# Algorithms: max flow problem and s-t minimum cut

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

Let G be an input graph to the max flow problem. Let A be a minimum s-t cut
in the graph. Suppose we add 1 to the capacity of every edge in the graph. Is it necessarily
true that A is still a minimum cut? If so, prove it, if not give a counterexample

[Note: I think the answer is no, not necessarily, but I cannot come up with a counterexample]
Please note that this is a homework question, I am looking for a hint or any help I can get :)

Comment: Hint: how many edges does the cut cross?

Comment: Could you explain that with an example (Doesn't have to be the counterexample they are looking for, just an example to explain the hint :))

Comment: Consider cuts that cross a drastically different number of edges, such as a cut across 3 edges and a cut across 15 edges. How does the maximum flow across the two cuts change when the capacity of each edge is increased by 1?

Comment: just to make sure i am getting the hint correctly: the maximum flow can increase by a maximum of (# of edges in cut) but when the max flow increases by < (# edges the cut crosses) then the min cut has to change

Answer (score 1):

With user57368 remark it is easy to construct simple counterexamples.

E.g. V={A,B,C,D}, E={(A,B,2.5), (B,D,1), (C,D,1)}. Minimal cut is {(B,D), (C,D)} with weight 2.

If you add weight 1 to every edge, you get E2={(A,B,3.5), (B,D,2), (C,D,2)}. Here is minimal cut {(A,B)} with weight 3.5.